# Defining file paths in python with EOL string literal errors

Tags: python, string, literals

I'm trying to save figures to a certain directory. I'm trying to define the general path via below

```
path=r'D:\FLGPR Akela\YPG\test\'
```

Which I don't quite understand. I thought the r before the string would avoid the '\' error?

Comment: Best solution is to just use forward slashes.

Comment: Or no trailing backslash